# ES lint expecting to pass all the dependencies to useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component using a useState hook. This hook is called inside a useEffect hook

```
const [items, setItems] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  const newItem = {
    [item._id]: options
  };
  setItems({...items, ...newItem});
}, [options]);
```

this works as expected, when options changes, I create a new item with those options.

However, when I run lint I get an alert saying the useEffect is missing some dependency, but I can't pass item as a dependency as this will result in an infinite loop.

Am I missing something or there's a better way to do this and I should always pass all the properties used inside the useEffect hook as dependencies?

Comment: You can get `items` from `setItems` (see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), but it's unclear where `item` is coming from.

Comment: You can use setter which accepts a function `setItems(curr => ({...curr, ...newItem}));`

Comment: @jonrsharpe item is passed to the component as a prop

Comment: Then please include it in a [mre] (also: _"the useEffect is missing some dependency"_ ... which?)

Comment: I'm reading your code, and I think it's unlikely that you actually need state here at all (or you need it in a different place). If you can synchronously update the state of a component based on a prop (or something synchronously derived from a prop), you don't actually need state. This is a very common mistake that people make - too much state, state where it's unnecessary. It leads you to writing more, confusing `useEffects` when it would be much simpler to just get rid of the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to have to pass `items` into the dependency array, and create an infinite loop, you can pass a callback function to `setItems` in order to access the `items` state.

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  setItems((currentItems) => { // Access the current `items` state
    const newItem = {
      [currentItem._id]: options
    };
    return { ...currentItems, ...newItem };
  });
}, [options]);
```

Comment: @SergeySosunov I just noticed, thanks.

Comment: That works as expected as I just need to pass setItems and currentItem as dependencies but not currentItems. Thanks.